# ¿Qué debería usar ASP.NET (.NET Framework) o ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

Les explico, hice una programa en `visual studio 2017` en `windows form` con `C#` sobre ingresar productos, ventas, compras, etc, y reportes los cuales los hice con `report viewer`, pero ahora se quiere hacer una versión web, con `ASP.NET` y en mi `visual studio 2017` veo que hay estas dos opciones
`ASP.NET (.NET Framework)` y `ASP.NET Core`, nunca he hecho una página en `ASP.NET`, ¿cúal debo usar? Qué me recomiendan o que me pueden aconsejar hacer.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es solo mi opinion sino desde Microsoft recomiendan que si vas a empezar un nuevo proyecto y sobre todo web, que empieces con ASP.NET Core, y hay muchas razones por citar algunas:

- Es el framework por defecto y el que esta en desarrollo (.NET 6 ya en preview)
- Tiene muchos componentes nuevos y la ultima tecnologia (por ejemplo Blazor, SignalR) trabaja con .NET Core
- El rendimiento es muy superior siendo varias veces mas rapido que .Net Framework
- Es Multiplataforma, si lo deseas puedes alojar tu WebApp en Linux/Windows o incluso en MacOS
- Es Open-Source por tanto su desarrollo esta muy activo porque recibe muchas contribuciones de la comunidad
- Realmente no necesitas Visual Studio para desarrollar con .NET CORE, puede usar el editor VS Code sin problemas (u otro editor de texto)

Ahora los contras

- Report Viewer no existe en .NET Core(se debe buscar alternativas como generar los reportes en PDF con algun paquete en Nuget)
- Si usas procedimeintos almacenados tienes que configurar bien tu Entity framework si es que utilizarias este ORM
- Visual Studio 2017 solamente soporta .NET CORE version 2.1, la que ya esta un tanto desactualizada
- DataTables no se usan en .NET Core (aunque esto hasta puede ser un punto a favor)
- Algunas librerias de Net Framework podrian no estar disponibles para Net Core

algunos links de interes

https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/10-diferencias-entre-net-core-y-net-framework.aspx

https://ivorysoluciones.com/blog/diferencias-entre-net-core-y-net-framework/

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responderme y hasta darme el contra de lo que debería de cambiar con lo que ya he creado, es lo que quería.